# Extract all possible peptides from a string of amino acids

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the following string of amino acids:

```
s = 'SHVANSGYMGMTPRLGLESLLE*A*MIRVAS'
```

where `*` denotes a stop codon.

I want to extract all peptides (chains of amino acids, i.e. substrings) that fulfill the following conditions:

1. Chain starts with amino acid `M`
2. Chain ends in `*`

If I use the regular expression `M.*?\*` in Python on that specific string, it returns one peptide:

```
MGMTPRLGLESLLE*
```

This is only partially correct, because it ignores another possible solution:

```
MTPRLGLESLLE*
```

In other words, I need a regular expression that returns the two peptides:

```
MGMTPRLGLESLLE*
```

and

```
MTPRLGLESLLE*
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=(M.*?\*))
```

Use this. It uses a positive lookahead to check strings. Because it is a 0 width assertion, it can match all strings.

You can use it like:

```
print re.findall(r"(?=(M.*?\*))",x)
```

See the demo, http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/5.

Answer (score 0):

The package 're' doesn't seem to support overlapping matches (that's why `findall` or `finditer` won't find the two matches you want).

However, there's a new Python package called regex that seems to fix that: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex. You can install it with one of these two commands:

```
pip install regex 
easy_install regex
```

Importing package regex instead of re, the following script does what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import regex as re
s = "SHVANSGYMGMTPRLGLESLLE*A*MIRVAS"
matches = re.findall(r'M.*?\*', s, overlapped=True)
for match in matches: print match
```